# How to update column text value with the output of multiple if statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update

For e.g., my table structure is like -

```
id (int, auto_increment),
value_1_isChecked (int),
value_1 (text),
value_2_isChecked (int),
value_2 (text),
value_3_isChecked (int),
value_3 (text),
extra_info (text),
interpretation (text)
```

All the values (`value_1`, `value_2`, `value_3`), their checked status (in the form of 0 or 1), extra info is present in database (30k rows). **What I am trying is to update concatenated text in `interpretation`** cell which would like this (I know this is not the correct mySql format, I am writing it just for better understanding of my question) -

```
variable result='<b>Selected Values :-</b><br>';
If(value_1_isChecked = 1) Then
result = result + "<b>[A]. </b>" + value_1 + "<br>";
End If;
If(value_2_isChecked = 1) Then
result = result + "<b>[B]. </b>" + value_2 + "<br>";
End If;
If(value_3_isChecked = 1) Then
result = result + "<b>[C]. </b>" + value_3 + "<br>";
End If;
If(extra_info Is NOT NULL) Then
result = result + "<br><b>Extra info :-</b><br>" + extra_info;
End If;
Update myTable set interpretation = result;
```

I can't use `ELSEIF` because multiple values may have their checked status as true (1).

I know, how to achieve this in PHP, but it would take very long time to update thousands (approx. 30K) of rows, that's why I am trying to do it from mySql itself. But I am unable to form a proper query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this example help you

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ac56/3)

```
select 
     concat (
           case v1 when '1' then concat('<b>','v1','</b>') else '' end,
           case v2 when '1' then concat('<b>','v2','</b>') else '' end,
           case v3 when '1' then concat('<b>','v3','</b>') else '' end
       )
from table1
```

Just update the query to match your need and then rewrite as an `UPDATE`

Comment: Thanks. It helped. Problem almost solved. Just one thing. It's not working with `not null`. e.g. - `case extra_info when NOT NULL then concat('extra_info') else '' end`. What would be correct syntax to write with `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Finally found where I was making mistake, `Not Null` case statement would be like `case when extra_info is Not Null then concat('<b>Explanation :- </b><br>', extra_info, '<br>') else '' end`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw the `is null` part. But im glad you found it and solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` statement like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET interpretation = CASE WHEN value_1_isChecked = 1 THEN concat('<b>','value_1','</b>')
                          WHEN value_2_isChecked = 1 THEN concat('<b>','value_2','</b>')
                          WHEN value_2_isChecked = 1 THEN concat('<b>','value_3','</b>')
                          WHEN extra_info Is NOT NULL THEN concat('<b>','extra_info','</b>')
                          ELSE ''
END;
```

Comment: it appeared to be a better answer, but I don't know why it's behaving like `ELSEIF`. e.g. if `value_1_isChecked = 1`, it's not adding 2nd or 3rd value even when their checked status is true. On the other hand, slight modification of already posted answer solved my question, So selected that as answer. Sorry.